# Select Every Form Element Except Buttons with CSS3

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there a way with CSS3 to select every input-related element that does **not** have a `type` attribute of `button`, `reset`, `submit`, or a tag of `button`?  This is what I've gotten so far:

```
input:not([type="submit"]),
textarea {

    /* ... */

}

input:not([type="submit"]):focus,
textarea:focus {

    /* ... */

}

input:not([type="submit"]):hover,
textarea:hover {

    /* ... */

}
```

... but it's not as universal as it could be.  I'm wanting to apply some nice new transitions to solely input-related fields.  If these certain styles get applied to any buttons on the page, it begins to look strange.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Simply chain multiple `:not` selectors together:

```css
/* Fields */
input:not([type=button]):not([type=reset]):not([type=submit]):not([type=image]),
textarea {
  outline: 3px solid green;
}

/* Buttons */
input[type=button],
input[type=reset],
input[type=submit],
input[type=image],
button {
  outline: 3px solid red;
}

/* Both */
input,
button,
textarea {
  margin: 6px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Form elements</h1>
<p>Buttons should be outlined in red, fields in green.</p>
<button>Button</button>
<input type="button" value="Input Button">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="color">
<input type="date">
<input type="datetime-local">
<input type="email">
<input type="file">
<input type="hidden">
<input type="image" src="//placehold.it/100x40/ffff00/0000ff/?text=foo">
<input type="month">
<input type="number">
<input type="password">
<input type="radio">
<input type="range">
<input type="reset">
<input type="search">
<input type="submit">
<input type="tel">
<input type="text">
<input type="time">
<input type="url">
<input type="week">
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: Cool. Didn't know you could chain them like that.

Comment: You're a sexy-thought producing man.  Thanks for the hookup, *brosef*.  I can't believe I didn't think of this.

Comment: Funny enough, (using Firefox 35.0.1) chaining did not work for me when I tried  `*:not(input):not(select):not(textarea) `. Instead, `*:not(input,select,textarea)` seems to be the way to go. Not sure if the related CSS specs have changed since this answer was posted, but it seemed constructive to leave a comment in case someone needs a heads-up on this.

Answer (score -2):

I think you're going to have to bit the bullet and do this:

```
input[type=text],input[type=password],input[type=url],input[type=email],textarea,select{
    /* css */
}
input[type=text]:focus,input[type=password]:focus,input[type=url]:focus,input[type=email]:focus,textarea:focus,select:focus{
    /* css */
}
input[type=text]:hover,input[type=password]:hover,input[type=url]:hover,input[type=email]:hover,textarea:hover,select:hover{
    /* css */
}
```

Simply because there is no and feature in CSS so any following `:not()`s would cancel out the other `:not()`s